# A Simple Powershell Script. Why the extra "$()" in code?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a simple script below I was looking at, but I cant understand why the writer includes the following  `"$($_.samAccountName)"` I have tried the script with just `$_.samAccountName` and it works fine. Hopefully its an easy answer but why would you have the extra `$()` in the code?

Many thanks.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * |

foreach {

$props = [ordered] @{

GroupName = $_.Name

MemberCount = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($_.samAccountName)" | Measure-Object |   select -ExpandProperty Count

}

New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props

} | sort MemberCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there's no reason to use the `variable/expression expansion syntax` in this case.

Maybe the original writer, enclosing the value of `-Identity` parameter in double quotes, wants to be sure for the variable expansion.

Comment: Variable expansion is explained in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx).

Comment: Thanks both, that explains things. The article is great cheers vonPryz.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell does not evaluate object properties inside strings. If you have an expression like this:

```
"$_.samAccountName"
```

the variable (in this case the "current object" variable `$_`) is expanded to the return value of its `ToString()` method, while the remainder of the string (`.samAccountName`) remains unchanged. As a result you get something like this:

```
"CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com.samAccountName"
```

instead of the value of the group object's `samAccountName` property.

Using the subexpression operator `$()` within the string

```
"$($_.samAccountName)"
```

forces PowerShell to evaluate the object's property and put the result in the string.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $g = Get-ADGroup 'Domain Users'
PS C:\> $g

DistinguishedName : CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
Name              : Domain Users
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 072d9eda-a274-42ee-a4ee-b4c2810bb473
SamAccountName    : Domain Users
SID               : S-1-5-21-1227823062-450780232-214340840-513

PS C:\> $g.ToString()
CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
PS C:\> "$g"
CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
PS C:\> "$g.samAccountName"
CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com.samAccountName
PS C:\> "$($g.samAccountName)"
Domain Users
```

However, as [C.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494137/1630171) correctly said, in your particular case you don't need to enclose `$_.samAccountName` in double quotes at all. Using it like this:

```
$MemberCount = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.samAccountName | ...
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, thank you for a really good explanation. That is extremely helpful, cheers for taking the time to post that.