# Why does the WMI PSComputerName change based on this usage inserting into mysql database?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am writing a script to perform WMI queries, get the disk information from the server and put the info in a mysql database.  When I perform the following code, I get "\servernameootcimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:".PSComputerName" put in the DB for computername.

```
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $DiskInfo = get-wimobject -class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server

    foreach ($disk in $DiskInfo) {
        $command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO drives (computername) VALUES ('$disk.PSComputerName')"
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }

}
```

When I modify the code to the following by assigning $disk.PSComputerName to a variable and using that, I get the right output in the DB of just the server name.

```
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $DiskInfo = get-wmiobject -class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server

    foreach ($disk in $DiskInfo) {
        $name = $disk.PSComputerName 
        $command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO drives (computername) VALUES ('$name')"
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }

}
```

I realize I have a workaround in place, but I'm trying to understand the difference in this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell expands only variables in double quoted strings. In your query string

```
"INSERT INTO drives (computername) VALUES ('$disk.PSComputerName')"
```

only `$disk` is expanded (to the return value of its `ToString()` method), not the property `$disk.PSComputerName`. You need to put it in a subexpression to make powershell evaluate the property value:

```
"INSERT INTO drives (computername) VALUES ('$($disk.PSComputerName)')"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495851/1630171) for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Within an expandable string, you need to use substring syntax - $() - to reference a property of an object.

```
$command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO drives (computername) VALUES ('$($disk.PSComputerName)')"
```

otherwise the property reference .PSComputerName is interpreted as literal text to be appended onto the value of $disk.